# IIS application host config changes detection

Tags: c#, iis

I want observe any changes made to IIS applicationhost.config .I know i can using file system watcher to watch changes made to host config file . But how to detect the applicationhost file location in c#.Is there any API to notify the changes made in applciaitonsost.config

I know application host config reside in **%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config** . but is this default location for all windows environment and Is it changeable ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just going to put my two cents in and say that this is pointless. Proper change control and file permissions render your current goal unnecessary.

Comment: @Jonathon what you are trying to say? i cannot understand

Comment: @Mahendran, it is really bothersome to be monitoring this. You could allow only select users access to change the IIS application host config. I believe that is what Jonathon means.

Comment: You should rather explain why you want to monitor the file for changes? What is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an auditing policy to monitor updates to the `applicationHost.config` file - that way, those update events show up in Event Viewer.  More details on that are described by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder).

The `applicationHost.config` file is also updated when IIS deployments occur.